# Linux terminal like parsing

Tags: parsing, console, go, linux

I'm creating a program that will hopefully operate like linux terminal (basic commands) for learning purposes.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)
/*
type FileDir struct {
    Name        string
    Permissions string
    Owner       string
    ModifyDate  int64
    Size        int32
    IsDir       bool
}
*/

func handleInput(input string) {
    tokens := strings.Split(strings.TrimSpace(input), " ")
    // cmd := tokens[0] // will be used later
    options := make(map[string]int)
    var positional []string

    if len(tokens) > 1 {
        // get options
        for j := 1; j < len(tokens); j++ {
            if strings.HasPrefix(tokens[j], "--") {
                options[tokens[j][2:]] = 1
            } else if strings.HasPrefix(tokens[j], "-") {
                if len(tokens[j]) == 2 {
                    options[tokens[j][1:]] = 1
                } else {
                    for _, flag := range tokens[j][1:] {
                        options[string(flag)] = 1
                    }
                }
            } else {
                positional = append(positional, tokens[j])
            }
        }
    }

    // handling of above input, based on cmd
    /* switch cmd {
        // ...
           case "ls" {
            _, hiddenFlag := options["a"]
            _, hiddenBig := options["all"]
            _, long := options["l"]
            _, human := options["h"]
            if len(tokens) == 1 {
                contents := getContentNames(false) // returns []string
                sort.Strings(contents)
                fmt.Println(strings.Join(contents, "  "))
            } else {
                // TODO  details
                if long {
                    contents := getContents(hiddenFlag || hiddenBig) // returns []FileDir
                    sort.Sort(ByName(contents))
                    for _, fileDir := range contents {
                        d := "-"
                        if fileDir.IsDir {
                            d = "d"
                        }
                        var s string
                        if human {
                            s = formatBytes(fileDir.Size)
                        } else {
                            s = fmt.Sprintf("%7d", fileDir.Size)
                        }
                        // WIP
                        fmt.Printf("%s%s %s %s %s MON DY HH:MM %s\n", d, fileDir.Permissions, fileDir.Owner, fileDir.Owner, s, fileDir.Name)
                    }
                } else {
                    contents := getContentNames(hiddenFlag || hiddenBig)
                    sort.Strings(contents)
                    fmt.Println(strings.Join(contents, " "))
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
        }*/
}

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var userInput string
    for {
        fmt.Printf("[root@FAKE /]$ ")
        scanner.Scan()
        userInput = scanner.Text()
        if userInput == "exit" || userInput == "quit" || userInput == "logout" {
            break
        }
        handleInput(userInput)
    }
}
```

At this time I want to know if the parsing of options I'm currently doing is the most optimal/efficient way for basic linux commands (ls (`-alhs` vs `-l` vs `-l -a`), man [cmd], cd [loc], tail -f #, etc) so that flags together and/or separate will be able to be later handled. I did include my current handling of the command `ls` but this section is WIP. If there is a radical change to the way I've done things it might be nice to show how it would optimize of `ls` handling (but this isn't necessary)

Comment: Why is there so much commented-out code?

Comment: @Harith I am asking about parsing optimization. The code should parse all options without as it is without the commented code. The commented out code is handling after the parsing, just to show that variables (`cmd`, `options`, etc) which are currently unused are used, and how I plan on using parsed input